# Iterate read-only properties in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

I'm trying to iterate through a COM object class to list all the properties, but readonly properties are not coming through. The class is defined with many properties but here are a couple ...

```
property RecLineSpacing: Integer dispid 123;
property RecLinesToPaperCut: Integer readonly dispid 124;
```

The code I'm iterating with is ...

```
function PropertyValues(const AObject: TObject) : TStringlist;
var
  PropIndex: Integer;
  PropCount: Integer;
  PropList: PPropList;
  PropInfo: PPropInfo;
const
  TypeKinds: TTypeKinds = [tkUnknown, tkInteger, tkChar, tkEnumeration, tkFloat,
    tkString, tkSet, tkClass, tkMethod, tkWChar, tkLString, tkWString,
    tkVariant, tkArray, tkRecord, tkInterface, tkInt64, tkDynArray, tkUString,
    tkClassRef, tkPointer, tkProcedure];
begin
  result:=tstringlist.Create;
  GetMem(PropList, SizeOf(PropList^));
  try
    PropCount := GetPropList(AObject.ClassInfo, TypeKinds, PropList);
    for PropIndex := 0 to PropCount - 1 do
    begin
      PropInfo := PropList^[PropIndex];
      result.Add ('['+propinfo.Name+']');
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(PropList);
  end;
end;
```

In this case the output lists RecLineSpacing but not RecLinesToPaperCut. Any idea why this would be?

Thanks
Terry

Comment: Maybe RecLineSpacing is published but not RecLinesToPaperCut in the class that implements the interface?

Comment: You should be using the overloaded version of `GetPropList()` that allocates the `PPropList` for you, as you are not retrieving the property count in order to allocate the list correctly yourself.  Also, which version of Delphi are you using? Maybe your version simply does not generate RTTI for `readonly` properties.

Comment: From the fact that classic Published-only RTTI is being used, I gather that this might be "as designed".

Comment: Looking further I see that it is indeed the un-published fields I am missing (thanks Warren). I understand that rtti might give me the answers but it says the object is not registered as a com class. I find this puzzling given that the object is an activex (OPOS) control that is imported to Delphi. Googling this doesn't seem to help...